# Use SVG from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, svg, quasar-framework

I created a node_module with all svg files to modularize our architecture.

It works fine when I call it using:

```
<q-icon>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="~svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg#addicon"></use>
  </svg>
</q-icon>
```

However when doing like this:

```
<q-icon>
  <svg>
    <use :xlink:href="'~svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg#' + iconParameter"></use>
  </svg>
</q-icon>
```

And `iconParameter` is defined below as:

```
iconParameter: 'addicon'
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?0594:6757 GET http://localhost:8080/~svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I also tried this and it works:

```
<use xlink:href="../../../../../../../../node_modules/svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg#addicon"></use>
```

But this one doesnt:

```
<use :xlink:href="'../../../../../../../../node_modules/svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg#' + iconParameter"></use>
```

Nor

```
<use :xlink:href="'../../../../../../../../node_modules/svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg#addicon'"></use>
```

Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vue-loader` does not convert expressions into webpack module requests.

You have to manually call `require`. [This is what `vue-loader` does internally](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules).

```
<q-icon>
  <svg>
    <use :xlink:href="require('~svgmodule/svgs/icons.svg') + '#' + iconParameter"></use>
  </svg>
</q-icon>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!